# use of substring gives a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1 exception

Tags: java

While searching, the string at tag is 
`abc: xyz`

But this gives the

```
`StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`: String index out of range: -1 exception.
```

at the line:

```
tag = strLine.substring(0, strLine.indexOf(':'));
```

What could be the possible error?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `indexOf()` is returning -1. that means `:` doesn't exist in the input string. Print strLine and check what it prints

Comment: your string does not contain `:`.

Comment: tag=xyz:abc ??? or strLine = xyz:abc??

Comment: I don't know what exactly you missed, but it's working fine : http://ideone.com/HKc21z

Comment: Make sure that your `String` contains `:`

Comment: @vidya add more codes to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
strLine.substring(0, strLine.indexOf(':'));
```

The above code will try to substring from 0(inclusive) to some positive int value.
but `strLine.indexOf(':')` is returning `-1` beacuse `:` is not there in `strLine`. So finally the method becomes `subString(0, -1)`, which is giving you the error :-

`StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1 exception.`

Do something like this to prevent :-

```
int i = strLine.indexOf(':')
if(i != -1)
tag = strLine.substring(0, i);
else {//handle error here}
```

OR

```
try{
tag = strLine.substring(0, strLine.indexOf(':'));
}
catch(StringIndexOutOfBoundsException ex){
// catch here
}
```

PS:- `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` is a runtime exception, should not be catched but handled/fixed.

Answer (score 0):

When substring is not found by `indexOf` the result is -1 and this is not an allowed parameter to substring.

Answer (score 0):

It means your string doesn't contain `symbol(:)`. If your strLine="xyz:abc" then it will output

```
String output="xyz:abc".substring(0, "xyz:abc".indexOf(':'));
System.out.println(output);
```

Answer (score -1):

Whatever String you have provided it is working fine with that.
Please see below program for your reference:

```
public class Consistent {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String s= "abc: xyz";
        String s1 = "abc";
        System.out.println(s.substring(0, s.indexOf(':')));
        System.out.println(s1.substring(0, s1.indexOf(':')));// This line will give error whatever you are getting, as it is not found
//to avoid first check if the String contains this identifier
if(s1.contains(":"))
System.out.println(s1.substring(0, s1.indexOf(':')));//It will work fine now
}
}
```

Comment: He is asking for `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException `, which he is facing because `:` is not in the code.

Comment: Yes it was already explained in the above comment so i explained it in coding way....

Comment: And in program comments also i have mentioned the same.

Comment: You downgraded the score that's why.